# I have error with getconnection about its parameters?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

**Hello, I have a problem of compilation I have cannot what put in getconnection () to be able to connect me to my database.** 
 Netbeans say cannot find symbol about getconnection(). I don't know what I must to do for my problem. The code must compile in Java 1.5

```
public DeleteOutil(String outil, JButton toEnable) {
        this.outil = outil;
        this.toEnable = toEnable;
    }
    @Override
       public Void doInBackground() {
          PreparedStatement stmt=null;
            String wql = "DELETE  FROM outil WHERE id_outil=?";
            try {
                Connexion con = Connexion.getConnection();
                stmt = con.prepareStatement(wql);

                stmt.setString(1, "outil");
                stmt.executeUpdate();
          }
          catch (Exception e)   
            }
         finally {
       if ( stmt!=null ) {
              // fermer/libérer la ressource
           try {
              stmt.close();
           }
           catch (Exception e) {   
            }
       }
            }  return null;
        }

  **this my connect code:**

    public class Connexion  {
        String urlPilote="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";//Direction pour charger le pilote
        String urlBasedonnees="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdboiteoutil";// Direction pour la connexion à la base de données
        Connection conn;
        public Connexion () {
        //On charge  notre pilote
        try{
           Class.forName(urlPilote);
           System.out.println("Le pilote est chargé");
          }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
          System.out.println(ex);
         }
        // On se connecte à la base de donnée
        try{
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(urlBasedonnees,"root","");
            System.out.println("La Base de données est chargé");
        }
        catch(SQLException  ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
            }
        Connection ObtenirConnexion(){
             return conn;
         }     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code. As-is it will fail with NPE, because `stmt` is null when `stmt.setString` is executed.

Comment: I don't understand "As-is it will fail with NPE". I will put Connexion con = Connexion.getConnection(url,user,pwd);
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(wql);
  but url, usern pwd  cannot find symbol

Comment: In method `doInBackground` I see `stmt=null`, then `wql = "..."`, then `try {`, then two blank lines, then `stmt.setString`. I don't see any `Connexion.getConnection(...)` calls anywhere, and I don't see any implementation of such a method in your `Connexion` class (well, not one that takes 3 parameters anyway, if `ObtenirConnexion` is supposed to say `getConnection`).

Comment: now, I edit Connexion con = Connexion.getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(wql); but I don't know what I must put in getconnection()?

Comment: `Connexion` doesn't declare a static method called `getConnection`, so I'm assuming that your issue is that `Connexion.getConnection()` fails to compile. Please clean up your code, pare it down to just show your issue, and then actually state what your issue is, e.g. error message and line number if compile error, stacktrace if runtime error.

Comment: I did it but I just know what are parameter to put in getconnection().

Comment: Your `Connexion` class has NO static methods, but `Connexion.getConnection()` is a static call. Do you know what static methods are?

Comment: Honestlyno, I just want to know what I must write, please.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Answer updated for Java 5,

You should not be needing to register the JDBC driver, as that should be done automatically by the JDBC driver .jar file.

Assuming that the main purpose of `Connexion` is to encapsulate the database connection string and the credentials, your code would be as follows:

```
public class Connexion {
    private static final String urlBasedonnees = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdboiteoutil";

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(urlBasedonnees,"root","");
    }
}

public class DeleteOutil {
    // Constructor here

    public void doInBackground() {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM outil WHERE id_outil = ?";
        try {
            Connection con = Connexion.getConnection();
            try {
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                try {
                    stmt.setString(1, "outil");
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                } finally {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } finally {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Handle exception here
        }
    }
}
```

That code will create a new connection to the database every time `doInBackground()` is called. Since connecting to the database is a slow operation, you might want to keep the database connection alive between calls to doInBackground(), in which case you need to decide on where that connection is maintained, and how long the connection should stay alive.

Comment: I am really sorry I forget to tell you that the project is set to compile it in 1.5